# An app with multiple sections that the user goes through to complete

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have recently created an app that has multiple sections. At the moment, they are 4 sections.
 the user is required to go through all of the sections in order (1-4). But before the user can get to section two, they have to complete the first section. Then the second section will become available to them. This will be applied to all other sections too.

Any ideas how this can be done?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Dave.

Comment: What sections are you reffering to ? Inside a table view ? tab bar controller ?

Comment: I have four sections that are in a scroll view. Three of them will be locked, apart from the first one (Introduction). Once the user has gone through the Introduction, the second section will become free. This helpful?

Comment: And how is that related to Xcode? Are you using Xcode to create Excel Macros or what? Xcode is a tag that should only be used if your question is about problems you have with the IDE. That's not the case. You try to use Xcode to write an application for a platform (iOS or OS X) in a language (objective-c, objective-c++, swift, etc.). The technology you actually want to use would be a much better tag than Xcode. Xcode is just a tool.

Comment: I edited your tags. There are a ton of ways to do it. Just have a look here : https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I would realize it with an UIModalView:

When the four steps have to be done, I would initialize a new Modal view with which the user can interact.

When he's done with Modal View 1, a new modal view appears.